# Difference between the appDataPath and extensions location in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Why do the VS Code extensions live at a different location than any other user preferences/settings?

According to the [`getAppDataPath`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/f3b191ab38fb9f1717ce5ce3396bb41204ffb399/src/paths.js#L18-L25) logic in VS Code, the user-defined settings, such as the `settings.json`, `keybindings.json`, etc. go under:

- `/Users/You/Library/Application Support/Code/` (on macOS),
- `C:\\Users\\You\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\` (on Windows), and
- `/Users/You/.config/` (on Linux)

But the extensions are under `~/.vscode/extensions` on all supported platforms.
Does anyone know why don't they put the extensions under `${getAppDataPath}/extensions`?

Thank you!

Comment: X-Posted to vscode Gitter: https://gitter.im/Microsoft/vscode?at=5e53ecae901209179b3830ca

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question was posted [here](https://gitter.im/Microsoft/vscode?at=5e53f4475cd3836098c71c47).

> because the paths that you get from `getAppDataPath` are not for storing extensions, they are for configuration files
>
> at least on Linux they use `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, which is intended for configuration files and not a bunch of extensions